# non-unique indices cardinality

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table named transaction in my database with two indices as shown in the image below. Sometimes the non-unique index (account_id) shows a different cardinality. For example sometimes the two indices show same cardinality which should not be the case because the non-unique index has many duplicates as compared to PRIMARY which only has unique values. So far I have had to DROP and then recreate the non-unique index to solve the problem temporary. What might be the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem. Quoting the [reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-index.html):

> Cardinality
>
> An estimate of the number of unique values in the index. This is updated by running ANALYZE TABLE or myisamchk -a. Cardinality is counted based on statistics stored as integers, so the value is not necessarily exact even for small tables. The higher the cardinality, the greater the chance that MySQL uses the index when doing joins.

Since the value in Cardinality is just an estimate, you should not expect it to be 100% accurate.

Comment: thank you for that info. But see sometimes the column with the non unique column tends to increment its values by a number lets 13 for only certain rows in the table and I am trying to come up with a solution as to why this is happening?